# How to enable usedir module on Apache2 in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server

How to enable `userdir` module on `apahe2` on ubuntu and set the path to directory for specific user?
This statement in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default` is making fail apache service to restart.

```
UserDir ~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a standard Ubuntu installation, run

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

to enable it. See `man a2enmod` for more info.

For defining paths for `userdir`, see the "UserDir directive used" table at the [documentation at Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html), reproduced quickly here:

```
UserDir directive used    Translated path
-------------------------------------------------------
UserDir public_html       ~bob/public_html/one/two.html
UserDir /usr/web          /usr/web/bob/one/two.html
UserDir /home/*/www       /home/bob/www/one/two.html
```